# bash: can't output: ps -ef|grep to variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to insert the result of a command to variable using a Bash script on a Unix platform.
I need to use the next command: `ps -ef|grep <my process>`, but when I run it I got an error:

```
-bash: line 1: 5420: command not found
```

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps_result=$(ps -ef|grep exe)
echo "$ps_result"
```

I thing this is some syntax problem because the 'grep' command is colored in yellow, but I can't to fix it (I tried using back-quotes `` `…` `` but it didn't work either).

edited:
There is the debug output relevant for the part of the code:

```
+ ssh ######
++ ps -ef
++ grep exe
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added '#####' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
-bash: line 1: 5447: command not found
```

Here is the full code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh ##### << EOF
ps_result=$(ps -ef|grep exe)
echo "$ps_result"
EOF
```

I need the ps_result in order to do manipulations in it later.
* the ##### is edit here and not in the original code...

Comment: Should be no space after the `=`.

Comment: Please do not destroy the original question and invalidate the answers.  Please _add_ the new information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the trace shows, the problem is not in the code you posted, but in the code which calls this code.

A here document without quoting will interpolate the process substitutions locally before passing the script to `ssh`.  Use single quotes around the here document terminator after `<<` to fix that.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh ##### <<'EOF'   # Notice quotes here
ps_result=$(ps -ef|grep exe)
echo "$ps_result"
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Preliminary versions of the question

The initial version of the question had the code:

```
ps_result= $(ps -ef|grep exe)
echo $ps_result
```

This has a space after the assignment, which causes trouble.

#### Preliminary answer

No spaces around assignments in shell:

```
ps_result=$(ps -ef|grep exe)
echo "$ps_result"
```

What you had `ps_result= $(ps -ef|grep exe)` runs `ps | grep`, and captures the output.  It uses the first word of the output as a command name (`nikitag`, it seems) and runs that with the rest of the words in the output as arguments and with the environment variable `ps_result` set to an empty string.  And since you don't have a command called `nikitag`, it fails.

Be very, very, very careful with spaces in shell scripts.

#### After update to include `ssh` and here document

Now that the question has been updated to show what's really going on, it is relatively simple to explain the problem.  There's a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) and `ssh` involved too:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh ##### << EOF
ps_result=$(ps -ef|grep exe)
echo "$ps_result"
EOF
```

Because the `EOF` is not quoted, the `ps` command is executed on the local machine before the `ssh` is started, and the output of the command is put into the here document.  You need to quote the `EOF` at the start of the here document so that the document is transferred verbatim and executed on the remote machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh ##### << 'EOF'
ps_result=$(ps -ef|grep exe)
echo "$ps_result"
EOF
```

Comment: Oh dear; that's sad.  Are you going to tell us more about it, or are we just going to have to convey our deepest sympathies for your dead processes and go home?  Please update the question with the revised code that is still failing and the new error message.

Comment: Still have error: 
-bash: line 1: 5420: command not found

Comment: You don't get that if you typed the code I suggested accurately.  Please update the question with your revised code and the error message.  Have you tried debugging the script with `bash -x script.sh`?

Comment: I edited the question, the code now in same syntax as you suggested...

Comment: But there's a crucial difference between your code and my code, because my code does not try to execute a command based on a PID, but your code is still trying to do that — at least, that's my informed guess based on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added the last output. Please have a look. Sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score -1):

The code should be no need of spaces

```
#!/bin/bash
ps_result=`ps -ef|grep exe`
echo $ps_result
```

Comment: Suggesting the use of back-ticks instead of `$(…)` is definitely retrograde — a very bad idea.  You also need to explain what the change is and why it is critical.